# Testing VF page button that is not in the controller

Tags: visualforce, custom-controller

I need to produce test classes for some VF code and associated controllers that I have inherited for a community. I have hit a problem with the associated VF page for searching the SF org as I can't find a way to activate the search button on the page as it has no corresponding entry in the controller. When I try calling the search method directly it throws a null pointer exception.

Should I modify the controller so that I can trigger the test that way or is it possible via the ApexPages methods?

VF Page button code

```
       <div class="form-group">

            <apex:form styleClass="form-inline">

              <apex:inputText value="{!searchStr}" styleclass="form-control" style="width:200px" />
                &nbsp;<apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!soslDemo_method}"
                                reRender="error, enq, att, acc, SPID, meter" status="actStatusId" 
                                          styleClass="btn btn-info"/>

                <apex:actionStatus id="actStatusId">
                            <apex:facet name="start" >
                                <img src="/img/loading.gif"/>
                            </apex:facet>
                </apex:actionStatus>

              </apex:form>
```

Controller class

```
    public class AWSSearchControllerNew {

 Public List<Attachment> attList{get;set;}
 Public List<Case> enqList{get;set;}
 Public List<Account> accList{get;set;}
 Public List<PID__c> SPIDList{get;set;}
 Public List<Meter__c> meterList{get;set;}

 Public Boolean enqData {get;set;}
 Public Boolean attData {get;set;}
 Public Boolean accData {get;set;}
 Public Boolean SPIDData {get;set;}
 Public Boolean meterData {get;set;}
 Public String searchStr{get;set;}

   Public AWSSearchControllerNew(){
   enqData = false;
   attData = false;
   accData = false;
   SPIDData = false;
   meterData = false;
   searchStr = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Search');
   if(searchStr!=null || searchStr!=''){soslDemo_method();}
   }

  Public void soslDemo_method(){

   attList = New List<Attachment>();
   enqList = New List<Case>();
   accList = New List<Account>();
   SPIDList = New List<PID__c>();
   meterList = New List<Meter__c>();

   System.debug('searchStr++++++++++'+ searchStr);

   if(searchStr.length() > 1){
   String searchStr1 = '*'+searchStr+'*';
   String searchQuery = 'FIND \'' + searchStr1 + '\' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING  Case(CaseNumber, Status, Id, Type, Reason, SPID__c), Account(Id, Name, Type, Customer_Banner_Name__c, UPRN__c, VOA_BA_Reference__c), PID__c(Id, Name, SPID_Valid_From__c, Retailer__c, Hartlepool_SPID__c, Impacted__c), Meter__c(Id, Name, Meter_Size__c, Meter_Size_Other__c, Meter_Manufacturer__c,    Location_of_Meter__c), Attachment(Id, Name, Parent.Id)';
   List<List<sObject>> searchList = search.query(searchQuery);

   enqList = ((List<Case>)searchList[0]);
   accList = ((List<Account>)searchList[1]);
   SPIDList = ((List<PID__c>)searchList[2]);
   meterList = ((List<Meter__c>)searchList[3]);
   attList = ((List<Attachment>)searchList[4]);

       system.debug('enqList+++++++++' + enqList);

   enqData = enqList.size()> 0?true:false;
   attData = attList.size()> 0?true:false;
   accData = attList.size()> 0?true:false;
   SPIDData = SPIDList.size() >0?true:false;
   meterData = meterList.size() >0?true:false;

   if(enqList.size()==0 && attList.size()==0 && accList.size()==0 && SPIDList.size()==0 && meterList.size()==0){
       apexPages.addmessage(new apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.Error, 'Sorry no results returned'));
       return;
   }
   }
   else{
   apexPages.addmessage(new apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.Error, 'Please enter at least two characters'));
   return;
   }
  }
}
```

Test class

```
   @isTest(seeAllData=true)
public class AWSSearchController_Test {

    public static User UserRecord;

    Static {
        userRecord = WSC_DummyDataCreatorTEST.getUser(); 
        System.debug('userRecord.ContactId-------'+userRecord.ContactId);
        System.debug('userRecord.Id----------'+userRecord.Id);    
    }

    static  testMethod void searchTest() {

        PageReference pageRef = Page.AWSSearch;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        AWSSearchControllerNew newAWSSearch = new AWSSearchControllerNew();

        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Search','Test');

        newAWSSearch.soslDemo_method();
    }

}
```

**Execution log**

[image: Null pointer]

**Code coverage**

[image]

Comment: Isn't soslDemo_method the function you need to call? What behavior are you experiencing?

Comment: It is doing a null pointer exception - now edited in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test exposed a problem. The search string could be null if a user doesn't type in a value, which would crash the page. To fix that, check for null first.

```
if(searchStr != null && searchStr.length() > 1) {
```

Next, your unit test called the constructor before setting the search string parameter, so searchStr was null. To fix that, set the parameter before you call the constructor.

```
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Search','Test');
    AWSSearchControllerNew newAWSSearch = new AWSSearchControllerNew();
```

It's also advisable that you do keep a unit test that also tests the null search term condition as well. You wouldn't want to have your search page crash just because of a blank input field.

Comment: Yes I was going to add the null search test after this was working. Thanks,